# Ektron pageID in C#

Tags: c#, widget, ektron

I am creating a widget in Ektron CMS400 and I am trying to dynamically pull the page layout ID to then display the title.  Currently I have this code:

```
PageTitle = contentAPI.GetContent(110, Ektron.Cms.Content.EkContent.ContentResultType.Published).Title
```

I would like to replace the 110 with an actual reference to the ID of the current page ( not content block ) being displayed.  Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4):

You can save a database call by not getting the content again. The page layout has already been loaded.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the page Basedata.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The content or null if not on a PageBuilder layout</returns>
private ContentBase GetPageBasedata()
{
    PageBuilder myPage = this.Page as PageBuilder;
    if (myPage != null)
    {
        return myPage.Basedata;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This really helped me. Do you know in which database table Ektron stores page builder  pages.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, I feel silly.  Even though the pageid does not show up in the URL I can still reference it via Request["pageid"].  Oh, bother.

Comment: That might be due to having aliasing turned on - the URL in the browser will be www.example.com/AnArticleOnFoo which will be redirected to www.example.com/template.asxp?pageid=23&id=32

Answer (score 2):

This function will return the page ID of an Ektron Page.

```
public long GetPageID()
{
    long pageid = new long();

    Ektron.Cms.PageBuilder.PageBuilder myPage = this.Page as Ektron.Cms.PageBuilder.PageBuilder;
                if (myPage != null)
                {

                    pageid = myPage.Pagedata.pageID;
                }

}
```